# Increase memory limit to all Node.js processes

Tags: node.js

How to increase default memory limit to Node.js? I know about `max_old_space_size` but it is only for one run. Also, there is a problem when script runs another process or `npm` commands and so on. So it is difficult to handle all the situation.

I want to set memory limit globally, for example in `ENV` variables or something else. So every time when I run Node.js it has increased memory in all processes despite where there were executed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [NODE_OPTIONS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options). For example:

```
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8096 ts-node my/file.ts
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also try using [increase-memory-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit). Following scripts will do the job as per the docs.

`npm install -g increase-memory-limit`

`increase-memory-limit`